# Can I use using statement with RHV (right hand value)?

Tags: c#

I want to use `using` statement purely for scope management. Can I omit holding an explicit reference to the underlying object that implements `IDisposable`?

For example, giving this declaraions:

```
class ITransactionScope : IDisposable {}
class TransactionGuard : ITransactionScope {...}

class DbContext
{
    public IDisposable ITransactionScope()
    {
        return new TransactionGuard();
    } 
}
```

Can I do the following:

```
void main()
{
    var dbContext = new DbContext();

    using (dbContext.TransactionScope())
    {
        // the guard is not accessed here
    }
}
```

Is `TransactionGuard` instance alive during `using` statement?

Comment: You could try it.  Set a break point in the `Dispose()` method of the returned scope instance and see if it gets called.

Comment: I really hope you can because I use the same strategy and it works :)

Comment: If all you care about is scope management, can't you just put braces in the code (without the `using`) and that will be the explicit scope for the code inside?

Comment: @AdamV: ReuvenBass is I believe using "scope" to mean "the lifetime of the object", rather than "the region of code in which the name of the local variable may be used".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I want to use the `using` statement purely for scope management.

You should use the `using` statement for what it is designed for: disposing an unmanaged resource in a timely manner. If that's not what you're using `using` for, you're probably doing something wrong.

> Can I omit holding an explicit reference to the underlying object that implements `IDisposable`?

As another answer pointed out: you already typed the code in; you could have simply tried it.

Yes, you can do that. The compiler will create an invisible local variable for you and call `Dispose` on it.

I recommend that if you have further questions about the usage of `using` that you read section 8.13 of the C# 4 specification.

Comment: can you please have a look at my answer? Would not GC reclaim it?

Comment: @Aliostad: The C# specification states that `using(expr) s;` is exactly equivalent to `X temp = expr; try { s; } finally { if (temp != null) ((IDisposable)temp).Dispose();}`. Is your claim that the garbage collector will clean up temp *before* the call to `Dispose`?

Comment: @Eric Maybe you could talk to the MVC team about abusing C# features. ;) I don't mind this one though; it's a handy syntax, and it doesn't use reflection.

Comment: @EricLippert that was hypothesis. But apparently not correct. WILL DELETE THE ANSWER SHORTLY.

Answer (score 2):

It is alive until you dispose of it.  So, yes.

And this type of question is SO much easier for you to answer by just hiting the compile and run button.  YOU ALREADY TYPED THE CODE. TRY IT.

Comment: -1. This is not necessarily true. You might try and it works 100 times but not last time.

Comment: @Aliostad: I'm not following you. The criticism seems entirely warranted; the question could have been easily answered by simply trying it, or even better, by reading the documentation and then trying it. Can you give me an example of a program where a using statement works a hundred times in a row and then fails?

Comment: @EricLippert my point was that GC might reclaim it before the end of the using `statement`. hence my answer, so would be grateful if you can review it.